# About Classification of compact 2-manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, surfaces

I have question about classification of compact 2-manifolds.
I have read in some sources that every compact 2-manifold is diffeomorphic with sphere with n-holes or sphere with m-mobius strips for some natural n or m (e. g. torus is a sphere with 1 hole and klein bottle is a sphere with 2 mobius strips).
But shouldn't there also be a possibility to be a compact 2-manifold with some non-zero number of holes and some non-zero number mobius strips? I don't see a reason why there should be allowed only holes or only mobius strips.

Answer (score 3):

If $\Sigma$ is a closed connected two-dimensional manifold, then

- $\Sigma$ is diffeomorphic to the connected sum of $n \geq 0$ tori if $\Sigma$ is orientable, or
- $\Sigma$ is diffeomorphic to the connected sum of $m \geq 1$ real projective planes if $\Sigma$ is non-orientable.

What about surfaces which are connected sums of tori and real projective planes? The answer is that such a surface is diffeomorphic to the connected sum of real projective planes only. This follows from the fact that $T^2\#\mathbb{RP}^2$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{RP}^2\#\mathbb{RP}^2\#\mathbb{RP}^2$; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2124520/39599) for a proof, and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/568338/39599) for a visual illustration. So for $m > 0$, the manifold $nT^2\#m\mathbb{RP}^2$ is diffeomorphic to $(2n + m)\mathbb{RP}^2$.

Comment: Could You explain what You mean by $T^{2}$ and $#$ sign respectively - is it cartesian product? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, $T^{2}$ is a tori, sorry.

Comment: $\#$ denotes connected sum.

Comment: @MaciejFicek: Keep in mind, some phrases in your post should be formulated more rigorously in connected sum language, for example: "the sphere with $n$-holes" should be formulated as "the connected sum of $n$ copies of $T^2$".

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: Do you know who first realized that $\mathbb{RP}^2\#\mathbb{RP}^2\#\mathbb{RP}^2\simeq T^2  \#\mathbb{RP}^2$? Or it was too obvious in the birth of topology era?

Comment: @C.F.G: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(topology)#Monoid_structure), this is due to Walther von Dyck.